# How to find Ratio of number of values of every column to the primary key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table like this

```
Payment Id     customer Id      Staff Id       Rental Id      Amount       Last Update
  1                1               1             76           2.99       2005-05-25 11:30:37  
  2                1               1             573          0.99       2005-05-25 11:30:37
  3                1               2             1422         0.99       2005-05-25 11:30:37
  4                2               1             320          4.99       2005-05-25 11:30:37
  5                2               1             2128         2.99       2005-05-25 11:30:37
```

I have to find the ratio of a number of values of every column to the primary key. What should be the query?

Expected output:

```
customer Id       repeated   
1                    3
2                    2
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple [aggregate (GROUP BY) query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html) you want. (With respect, I don't understand your requirement for a *ratio*; your example output only shows row counts.)

```
SELECT `Customer id`, COUNT(*) repeated
  FROM the_table
 GROUP BY `Customer id`
 ORDER BY `Customer id`
```